# Java regex how to get value in brackets

Tags: java, regex

```
 lineIdentifier:dasda creationDate:[08/06/2018 00:00:00 TO *] text: [dasda, lll]
```

With `regex` I would like to get back only data in `creationDate`

`08/06/2018 00:00:00` and  `*`

This is my pattern but does not work

```
Pattern r = Pattern.compile("\\[(\\w*)\\]");
        Matcher m = r.matcher(result);

        if (m.find( )) {
            System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );
        }else {
            System.out.println("NO MATCH");
        }
```

any idea what i am doing worng?

Comment: `m.group(0)` is the entire match. You want `m.group(1)`

Comment: I always get NO MATCH

Comment: Is your String always formatted like this? Then you can get the indexes of [ and ] and use with substring()

Comment: What characters `\w` represents? Are all characters in `[....]` which you want to find matched by it (remember that spaces is also a character)?

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(".*(creationDate:\\[(.+?) TO (.+?)\\]?).*");
Matcher m = r.matcher("lineIdentifier:dasda creationDate:[08/06/2018 00:00:00 TO *] text: [dasda, lll]");

if (m.find( )) {
      System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(2) );
      System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(3) );
}else {
      System.out.println("NO MATCH");
}
```

Comment: @Lino Why? OP doesn't want to check if regex *matches* entire text, but to *find* specific part of it. Improvement of this answer wouldn't be using `matches()` but removing unnecessary `.*` at start and end of regex.

Comment: @Pshemo you're right, either use `matches` with `.*` or use `find` without `.*`